# Can't install driver for TP-Link T1U USB on Ubuntu 18.04 (kernel 4.15.0-36-generic)

Tags: 18.04, realtek-wireless, tp-link

I'm trying to install a Tp-Link T1U USB adapter on my machine.
I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04 with a 4.15.0-36-generic kernel.
I've been looking at a few solutions for a couple of days, namely:
https://github.com/ashaffer/rt3573sta
https://github.com/lixz789/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/pull/1

This is what I'm doing to install, following the README I downloaded and the suggested patch in the second link I posted:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
$ mkdir ~/src
$ cd ~/src
$ git clone https://github.com/Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.git
$ git clone https://github.com/lixz789/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.git
$ cd mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
$ make
```

This is what I get back:

```
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/tools'
/home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/tools/bin2h
chipset = mt7610u
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-36-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-36-generic'
Makefile:975: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
CC [M]  /home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o
In file included from /home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rtmp_os.h:44:0,
             from /home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rtmp_comm.h:75,
             from /home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rt_config.h:33,
             from /home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:28:
/home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/os/rt_linux.h:77:0: warning: "EXT_BUILD_CHANNEL_LIST" redefined
#define EXT_BUILD_CHANNEL_LIST  /* must define with CRDA */

<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/os/rt_linux.h:98:0,
             from /home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rtmp_os.h:44,
             from /home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rtmp_comm.h:75,
             from /home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rt_config.h:33,
             from /home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:28:
/home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/cfg80211.h:35:49: error: 'IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS' undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean 'IEEE80211_NUM_ACS'?
struct ieee80211_supported_band Cfg80211_bands[IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS];
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                             IEEE80211_NUM_ACS
/home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c: In function 'announce_802_3_packet':
/home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:341:16: warning: unused variable 'pAd' [-Wunused-variable]
RTMP_ADAPTER *pAd = (RTMP_ADAPTER *)pAdSrc;
            ^~~
In file included from /home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rtmp_os.h:44:0,
             from /home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rtmp_comm.h:75,
             from /home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rt_config.h:33,
             from /home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:28:
/home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c: In function 'STA_MonPktSend':
/home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:450:35: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'long unsigned int' [-Wformat=]
     DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("%s : Size is too large! (%d)\n", __FUNCTION__, pRxBlk->DataSize + sizeof(wlan_ng_prism2_header)));
                               ^                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/os/rt_linux.h:669:16: note: in definition of macro 'DBGPRINT_RAW'
     printk Fmt;               \
            ^~~
/home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:450:9: note: in expansion of macro 'DBGPRINT'
     DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("%s : Size is too large! (%d)\n", __FUNCTION__, pRxBlk->DataSize + sizeof(wlan_ng_prism2_header)));
     ^~~~~~~~
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o] Error 1
Makefile:1551: recipe for target '_module_/home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/momissimi/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-36-generic'
Makefile:403: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

I'm in no shape or form, capable of translating all that and have no idea how to move forward.

Any help would be great.

**NB**: I hope I haven't made a mistake posting anything. I did try following the guidelines, but I'm not all that familiar.

Comment: The code probably isn't compatible with the kernel version you're running. It was written for older versions.

Comment: Oh! Ok, that's interesting. I wonder if there's a way to get this adapter working with my kernel.
I've got a Mediatek MT7630e on this machine and it's slowing down my internet connection, if not losing it all together every now and then. :/

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh! The always tricky, never straightforward mt7610u!

This driver has a difficult history with later Linux kernels, for example, here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2367163&highlight=mt7610u You might be interested in my post #18.

However, post #4 here claims that it is now working! https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2375919 We shall soon find out.

With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u.git
cd mt7610u
make
sudo make installfw
sudo insmod mt7610u.ko
```

Before we proceed with further needed steps, tell us if a wireless interface is created:

```
iwconfig
```

...and if you can connect, pull web pages, etc., without difficulty.

**EDIT**: Let's be sure you have the 'master' branch. First, remove the possibly faulty file:

```
cd /home/momissimi
sudo rm -r mt7610u
git clone -b master https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u.git
cd mt7610u
make
sudo make installfw
sudo insmod mt7610u.ko
```

Any improvement?

Comment: Hi, sorry. I tried to reply earlier but did it the wrong way and my message got deleted.
Here's what I get when I type make
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rBk5ECIz1-GztuNN7GjJO5SVJmgh0tS2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you certain that you have *build-essential* installed? `sudo dpkg -s build-essential | grep Status` Are you certain that you cloned the 'master' branch?

Comment: I think I do:
    Status: install ok installed

Could you further explain cloning the master branch?

Comment: The master branch makes with one warning and no errors on my 4.15.0-36 kernel. See my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: Mmmhh... something happened. Not sure if installed though. Please keep in mind I do have a wireless connection on this machine, but the chipset is pathetic and keeps dropping the connection, hence the usb adapter.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wCuZQFghFMCs95EpVFFMRHFbIJq60-zP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: wlan0 Ralink STA appears to be the USB. Can you try to disconnect the internal at Network Manager and see if the USB will see networks and connect?

Comment: I went to Connections-System Settings (I'm guessing that's the Network Manager under Kubuntu 18.04? Correct me if I'm wrong). I restricted to device wlan0 (). However, it seems nothing's changed: connection is unstable, speed is stumped at 25Mbps (should be about 90 over WiFi) and the device doesn't show up in Network Interfaces. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xMre-nBKuotq3oxaE8DIQ1Pr0iK0Oyqq/view?usp=sharing
By the way, I'm incredibly grateful for the help. :)

Comment: As I said at the outset, "The always tricky, never straightforward mt7610u! This driver has a difficult history with later Linux kernels." We can keep troubleshooting the mt7610u, which, so far, shows no sign of life at all, or, and I prefer this, troubleshoot the at least sort of working internal device. What would you like to do?

Comment: The issue with the original internal device (Mediatek MT7630e) is that it doesn't support 5Ghz frequencies, ultimately stumping the speed of my new broadband internet connection. I guess there could be a way to at least make it stable, but the thing is before I got the usb adapter the connection was wonky even under Windows (this machine's a dual boot). If it's alright by you (and I mean this, I'm taking up your time) I'd at least like to try and get the external adapter working under ubuntu. However, do let me know if you've had enough. :)

Comment: We might have better luck with the USB if we blacklist (easily reversible) the internal. Is its driver rt2800pci? `lsmod`

Comment: Here you go. :) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yyTE7cEJapVCKsh6vuHSj0Lo1mxY24jw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please try: `sudo ifconfig wlp3s0f0 down && sudo modprobe -r mt7630e` Followed by: `cd  mt7610u && sudo insmod mt7610u.ko` Is there any improvement? `iwconfig` If so, we'll blacklist mt7630e.

Comment: Hmmmm... says sudo: ifconfig: command not found

Comment: Oops! Please substitute: `sudo ip link set wlp3s0f0 down`

Comment: Ok, so here's what happened: took it down, typed second command --> signal strength bars were full. Tried to load a page, nothing happened. Went to check Network Interfaces --> wlp3s0f0 was indeed down but there was no new device listed. Brought wlp3s0f0 back up, repeated steps, got this *insmod: ERROR: could not insert module mt7610u.ko: File exists* but still no connection. :(

Comment: Frankly, I have had *no* success with any mt7610u device in many years. My strong sense is that we could troubleshoot, tweak, review the logs for weeks but probably still not have success. There are other fully supported USB devices available that will work out of the box. Frankly, I'd rather troubleshoot the mt7630e internal device.

Comment: Ok then! We gave it a shot, and I'm very grateful. I'm happy to try stabilise the Mediatek device. In the meantime, could you maybe give an idea of which USB devices could function with my ubuntu setup? I hope it isn't too much to ask. :)

Comment: Not at all: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2397914 Please start a new question about your mt7630e and describe your symptoms and include: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280` and `lsmod | grep mt7`

Comment: Fantastic! You are a star, thanks. 
Sent you an email, by the by. :)

Answer (score 0):

Kernel 4.19 has a working drive.

To install:

1. Open http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ and select the latest kernel version folder.
2. Download .deb for `linux-headers`, `linux-headers-generic`, `linux-image` and `linux-modules` and install.
3. Reboot