# Mediatek MT7630e WiFi chipset unstable conection

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, mediatek

I have a Mediatek wireless chipset on my Asus laptop. Unfortunately, it isn't performing correctly. The connection is unstable sometimes falling altogether. I'm running a dual boot with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 18.04 (Kernel 4.15.0-36-generic) with a KDE environment.
I asked a previous question trying to get a TP-Link Tu1 v2 USB wireless adapter to work under windows, but no luck.

[Can't install driver for TP-Link T1U USB on Ubuntu 18.04 (kernel 4.15.0-36-generic)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083281/cant-install-driver-for-tp-link-t1u-usb-on-ubuntu-18-04-kernel-4-15-0-36-gener/1083342?noredirect=1#comment1784310_1083342)

Despite the fact that my internal chipset is unable to pick up 5Ghz frequencies, thus slowing down the connection, I'd like to find out if I can at least make it stable.

Here are the outputs for two commands chili555 suggested I include in my question:

```
momissimi@Kakamoko:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
```

---

```
momissimi@Kakamoko:~$ lsmod | grep mt7 
mt7630e               180224  0
mac80211              778240  1 mt7630e
mt76xx                 20480  0
cfg80211              622592  2 mac80211,mt7630e
eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 mt7630e
```

As always, any help is highly appreciated. :)

EDIT:
Driver for Mediatek chipset was downloaded from here:
https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1796
This is the only one I could get to work.

```
wlp3s0f0  Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
                Channel:11
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Quality=70/70  Signal level=40 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"TIM-30912577"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                          24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000008eb9e10cb4
                Extra: Last beacon: 68ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000C54494D2D3330393132353737
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                IE: Unknown: 03010B
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                IE: Unknown: 2D1A7E181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D160B081100000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                IE: Unknown: 7F080500000000000040
                IE: Unknown: DD8E0050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010DB3FACB110955BAD814CDEFAC57044331021000B546563686E69636F6C6F721023000E4D656469614163636573732054471024000937383976616320763210420009313831305341394E511054000800060050F2040001101100074147434F4D424F10080002268C103C0001031049000600372A000120
```

---

```
modinfo mt7630e | grep version
version:        2.3.8
version:        2.3.8
version:        2.3.8
version:        2.3.8
version:        2.3.8
version:        2.3.8
srcversion:     F8B691AE2F721FE1A2079D3
```

Comment: From where did you download the driver? Also, please edit your question to show the result of: `sudo iwlist  scan` Omit all the neighbors, show only your trpublesome SSID, redact the MAC address with xxxx. Also, please edit your question to show: `modinfo mt7630e | grep version`

Comment: WPA2-AES!!! Awesome! Also, the driver you linked is also the only one I know of that works.

Comment: I'll give you more random letters and numbers if it makes you happy! XD I'm kidding. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that I suggest that you try. First, let’s turn off power saving in Network Manager; from the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Next, let’s try a driver parameter; again, from the terminal:

```
echo "options mt7630e nohwcrypt=Y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/mt7630e.conf
```

Now, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

If your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Here is an interesting thread about auto channel selection: https://superuser.com/questions/1311149/why-do-wifi-routers-do-such-a-bad-job-of-channel-selection

After making these changes, reboot the computer and let us hear your report.

Comment: Oki-doki. I'll get on it tomorrow morning (it's 11:30 pm here, will be going to bed soon). Will get back to you ASAP.

Comment: "save and close the text editor" <--- help?! O.o

Comment: This is what I've got so far: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1olk12MGm2Wc2CMNXESdu0odPy2bjrFcv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Save is Ctrl+o and exit is Ctrl+x.

Comment: OK, rebooted and now it's refusing to connect. Gets stuck on "setting network address"

Comment: Normally, 'setting network address' would be associated with a static IP address. Aren't you using Network Manager and DHCP? Did you reboot (power cycle) the router? Any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep -e wlp -e mt7`

Comment: Network Manager: I'm under KDE, so I'm guessing it's this? Please don't laugh! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sAu8USxhuLDwurkmLUha5lO0KBDs_UcA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: DHCP: went into router settings, seems like it's been set up that way automatically (this is a new router). dmesg | grep -e wlp -e mt7 -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ucX-9i61iybYL8bg7w_RbORCYl8XO1Zr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: No laughs, you are doing just fine. Let's revert the driver parameter and try again: `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/mt7630e.conf` Reboot the computer, try to connect and let us see again: `dmesg | grep wlp`

Comment: Aaand we're back! dmesg | grep wlp -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JRHIj9u-9JnPkjdMLl6-cmJZx7Uki8zx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ahhh! Much better. Is it stable? You may need to test for a while.

Comment: The signal bars keep going up and down like crazy, but I don't know if that really means anything. What concerns me more is the results I get on speedtests. It looks like an ECG O.o (I'm overdoing it, but it isn't stable by any means) It's also really slow, but I'm afraid this is the best we can do until I get my hands on an external adapter that will work under 18.04. Do you agree?

Comment: I regrettably agree. Could you consider changing the internal device??

Comment: Eeek! On a laptop?! I mean, I'm game for anything but can it even be done?

Comment: Let's continue in email. See you there.